# how to show the data in check box

Tags: php, zend-framework

My output is like this:- 
when i `print_r ($aResultData)`

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [parent] => SK336 [child] => CP ) [1] => Array ( [parent] => SK336 [child] => PES ) [2] => Array ( [parent] => SK995 [child] => MS ) [3] => Array ( [parent] => SK995 [child] => LSW ) [4] => Array ( [parent] => SK995 [child] => GES ) [5] => Array ( [parent] => SK995 [child] => RSW ) )
```

Now I want to show this data into a checkbox in php.

```
            parent  child
checkbox    SK336   CP
checkbox    SK336   PES
checkbox    SK995   MS
checkbox    SK995   LSW
checkbox    SK995   GES
checkbox    SK995   RSW
```

and a submit button

and after submit checkbox (it depends what i am selected) and finally it stores in to another database what i can do ?

Comment: Can you be more specific on which datas to be shown do you want all the parents and child to be shown or just one

Comment: Still there is a confusion. DO you want checkbox for both parent and child or jsut one checkbox and show parent and child??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do like:

```
$parents = array();
$childs = array();
foreach ($aResultData as $aResultDataValue) {
      $parents [$aResultDataValue['parent']] = $aResultDataValue['parent'];
      $childs [$aResultDataValue['parent']][] = $aResultDataValue['child'];
}

foreach ($parents as $parent) {
     echo '<div>';
     echo '<div><input type="checkbox" name="parents[]" value="'.$parent.'" id="parents_'.$parent.'"/>
     <label for="parents_'.$parent.'">'.$parent.'</label></div>';
     foreach ($childs[$parent] as $child) {
            echo '<div style="margin-left:15px;"><input type="checkbox" name="childs[]" value="'.$child.'" id="childs_'.$child.'"/>
            <label for="childs_'.$child.'">'.$child.'</label></div>';
     }
    echo '</div>';
}
```

Hope this helps

**EDIT:**

If you want to check all child checkbox if parent is selected then you need to c=use jQuery and also had to change PHP code:

PHP Code:

```
$parents = array();
$childs = array();
foreach ($aResultData as $aResultDataValue) {
     $parents [$aResultDataValue['parent']] = $aResultDataValue['parent'];
     $childs [$aResultDataValue['parent']][] = $aResultDataValue['child'];
}

foreach ($parents as $parent) {
     echo '<div>';
     $parent_value = "'$parent'";
     echo '<div><input type="checkbox" name="parents[]" value="'.$parent.'" id="'.$parent.'" class="parentCheck"/>
     <label for="parents_'.$parent.'">'.$parent.'</label></div>';
     foreach ($childs[$parent] as $child) {
           echo '<div style="margin-left:15px;"><input type="checkbox" name="childs[]" value="'.$child.'" id="childs_'.$child.'" class="child_'.$parent.'"/>
           <label for="childs_'.$child.'">'.$child.'</label></div>';
     }
     echo '</div>';
}
```

JS CODE:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
     // add multiple select / deselect functionality
    jQuery(".parentCheck").click(function () {
       var childId = jQuery(this).attr('id');
       jQuery('.child_'+childId).attr('checked', this.checked);
    });
});
```

**NEW EDIT :**

If you want to uncheck the parent when a child is unchecked and check the parent when all the child are selected you can use this:

PHP CODE:

```
$parents = array();
$childs = array();
foreach ($aResultData as $aResultDataValue) {
     $parents [$aResultDataValue['parent']] = $aResultDataValue['parent'];
    $childs [$aResultDataValue['parent']][] = $aResultDataValue['child'];
}

foreach ($parents as $parent) {
     echo '<div>';
     $parent_value = "'$parent'";
     echo '<div><input type="checkbox" name="parents[]" value="'.$parent.'" id="'.$parent.'" class="parentCheck"/>
     <label for="parents_'.$parent.'">'.$parent.'</label></div>';
     foreach ($childs[$parent] as $child) {
           $child_value = "'$child'";
               echo '<div style="margin-left:15px;"><input type="checkbox" name="childs[]" value="'.$child.'" id="childs_'.$child.'" class="child_'.$parent.'" onclick="checkParent('.$parent_value.','.$child_value.');"/>
              <label for="childs_'.$child.'">'.$child.'</label></div>';
     }
     echo '</div>';
}
```

JS CODE:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
      // add multiple select / deselect functionality
      jQuery(".parentCheck").click(function () {
           var childId = jQuery(this).attr('id');
           jQuery('.child_'+childId).attr('checked', this.checked);
      });
 });
 function checkParent(parentId,childId) {
    if(jQuery(".child_"+parentId).length == $(".child_"+parentId+":checked").length) {
           $('#'+parentId).attr("checked", "checked");
       } else {
           $('#'+parentId).removeAttr("checked");
       }
 }
```

This thing works :)

Comment: :) Exactly but i also want to select all if i select parent see my this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9038135/how-to-show-data-with-checkboxes-in-zend-framework

Comment: :) this works for me thanks but i want when i deselect any of the child for example LSW thenafter its parent for example SK995 also automatic deselect

Comment: @Sabari +1 for a correct answer and all your edits. Good work!

Comment: @Sabari :) now finally i want to insert all those data in to tagaccess table what i can do

Comment: if your from submit method is post . you can get all the checked parents in $_POST['parents'] as an array of values and also the childs in $_POST['childs'] as an array of values. YOu can get the values from those arrays and insert it in to the db in the way your db structure is created.

Comment: @Sabari:)I am using zend Framework and I want to put this code in my form how it is possible ? Do you have knowledge about zend ?